# Scroll View keeps discarding the bottom View from displaying

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, android-scrollview, android-relativelayout

I've created a preference UI but the thing is I can't let the bottommost child view to be displayed on the device. It keeps discarding the bottommost view. Though this query is similar to one I found in the query list yet the problem I'm facing left me with no debugging ways or I'm missing some serious property.
My code is:
The Bottom `TextView` which I finally wrapped inside a relativeView is the part which is discarded.
To ,y wonder I changed to `LinearLayout` from Relative built I guess It might have some issues as well..
But the most important query is that it doesn't scroll till the end of the Activity.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".Preferences">

   <RelativeLayout
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="60dp"
       android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
       android:id="@+id/header"
enter code here
       >
       <ImageView
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:id="@+id/back_key"
           />
       <TextView
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:id="@+id/text_prefer"
           android:layout_centerInParent="true"
           android:layout_centerVertical="true"
           android:text="@string/activity_name"
           android:textColor="@color/white"
           android:textStyle="bold"
           android:textSize="18sp"
           />

   </RelativeLayout>
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/wrapper_scroll"
        android:layout_below="@id/header"
        >
        <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/scroll_horizontal"
            android:fillViewport="true"
            >
            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="11dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="11dp"
                android:id="@+id/rel_scroll"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                >
                <RelativeLayout

                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="120dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/rounded_back_for_layout"
                    android:id="@+id/rel_age_layout"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                    >
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_margin="18dp"
                        android:id="@+id/age_text"
                        android:text="@string/age"
                        android:textSize="14sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:textColor="@color/magenta_brown"
                        />
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_margin="18dp"
                        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                        android:text="18-26"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:textSize="14sp"
                        android:textColor="@color/black"

                        />

                </RelativeLayout>
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/text_age_pref"
                    android:layout_below="@id/rel_age_layout"
                    android:text="@string/age_prefer"
                    android:textSize="10.5sp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
                    />
                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="45dp"
                    android:layout_below="@id/rel_age_layout"
                    android:background="@drawable/rounded_back_for_layout"
                    android:id="@+id/rel_interest_layout"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                    >
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_margin="16dp"
                        android:id="@+id/interested_in_text"
                        android:text="@string/interested_in"
                        android:textSize="14sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:textColor="@color/magenta_brown"
                        />
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="18dp"
                        android:layout_below="@id/interested_in_text"
                        android:text="@string/men"
                        android:textSize="14sp"
                        android:textColor="@color/black"
                        android:id="@+id/men"
                        />
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="18dp"
                        android:layout_below="@id/men"
                        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                        android:text="@string/women"
                        android:textSize="14sp"
                        android:textColor="@color/black"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                        />
                </RelativeLayout>
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/interested_pref"
                    android:layout_below="@id/rel_interest_layout"
                    android:text="@string/interested_prefer"
                    android:textSize="10.5sp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
                    />

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="38dp"
                    android:layout_below="@id/rel_interest_layout"
                    android:background="@drawable/rounded_back_for_layout"
                    android:id="@+id/rel_alerts_layout"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                    >
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_margin="18dp"
                        android:id="@+id/alerts_mode"
                        android:text="@string/alerts"
                        android:textSize="14sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:textColor="@color/magenta_brown"
                        />
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="18dp"
                        android:layout_below="@id/alerts_mode"
                        android:text="@string/sound"
                        android:textSize="14sp"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="14dp"
                        android:textColor="@color/black"
                        />
                </RelativeLayout>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/sound_prefer"
                    android:layout_below="@id/rel_alerts_layout"
                    android:textSize="10.5sp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
                    />
                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="45dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                    android:layout_below="@id/rel_alerts_layout"
                    android:background="@drawable/rounded_back_for_layout"
                    android:id="@+id/rel_matchmaker_layout"
                    >
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_margin="18dp"
                        android:id="@+id/matchmaker_text"
                        android:text="@string/matchmaker"
                        android:textSize="14sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:textColor="@color/magenta_brown"
                        />
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="18dp"
                        android:layout_below="@id/matchmaker_text"
                        android:text="@string/hide_my_prof"
                        android:textSize="14sp"
                        android:textColor="@color/black"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"

                        />
                </RelativeLayout>
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/matchmaker_prefer"
                    android:text="@string/matchmaker_prefer"
                    android:layout_below="@id/rel_matchmaker_layout"
                    android:textSize="12sp"

                    />
                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="38dp"
                    android:layout_below="@id/rel_matchmaker_layout"
                    android:background="@drawable/rounded_back_for_layout"
                    android:id="@+id/rel_whitelist_layout"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                    >
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_margin="18dp"
                        android:id="@+id/whitelist_text"
                        android:text="@string/whitelist"
                        android:textSize="14sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:textColor="@color/magenta_brown"
                        />
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_margin="18dp"
                        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                        android:text="@string/go"
                        android:padding="10dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/edittext_rectangle_border"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:textSize="14sp"
                        android:textColor="@color/black"
                        />
                </RelativeLayout>

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@id/rel_whitelist_layout"
                    >
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textSize="10.5sp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
                        android:text="@string/whitelist_prefer"
                        />
                </RelativeLayout>
            </LinearLayout>

        </ScrollView>

    </RelativeLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Here's the screenshot:

[image]

Comment: @azizbekian I've added this screenshot and see the bottom text is not visible. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1eA-Gz0JNa6LhPlFHXR2s0UR9ZTXGGTuX/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the height of the ScrollView from match_parent to wrap_content:

```
<ScrollView
...
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
... >
```

Comment: I've already performed that part and it didn't work. Thanks for the suggestions as it let me to debug through simple aspects and yeah I finally was able to rule out my problem. The comment below speak appropriate about the margin thing and I settled this problem by adding a bottom margin of 10dp. Thanks .

Answer (score 0):

I tried your xml and this worked.
Add this to your last `TextView`

```
android:layout_margin="18dp"
```

Your last element will be:

```
  <RelativeLayout
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_below="@id/rel_whitelist_layout">
          <TextView
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:textSize="10.5sp"
              android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
              android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
              android:layout_margin="18dp"  
              android:text="@string/whitelist_prefer"/>
  </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion as it was really helpful and really did work. I did make a slight change as I added a bottom margin of 10dp and it worked as well... Thank you..